# Noah’s wine what is it?Healthy

Tags: wine, history

You mention that there is a wine similar yet you do not give it a name. Please give the name of a wine that resembles the wine Noah made

Comment: Hi Pam, and welcome to the site.  Who mentioned this?  It's not clear from your question as currently worded.

Comment: This should be closed because I think they are talking about this post. https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/7383/is-there-a-modern-wine-that-is-designed-to-resemble-noahs-wine